# Hadoop - Mappers not emitting anything

Tags: hadoop

I'm running the code below and no output is generated (well, the output folder and the reducer output file are created, but there is nothing wihtin the `part-r-00000` file). From the logs, I suspect the mappers are not emitting anything.

The code:

```
package com.telefonica.iot.tidoop.mrlib;

import com.telefonica.iot.tidoop.mrlib.utils.Constants;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Count extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Count.class);

    public static class UnitEmitter extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

        private final Text commonKey = new Text("common-key");

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(commonKey, new LongWritable(1));
        } // map

    } // UnitEmitter

    public static class Adder extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0;

            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            } // for

            context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        } // reduce

    } // Adder

    public static class AdderWithTag extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {

        private String tag;

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            tag = context.getConfiguration().get(Constants.PARAM_TAG, "");
        } // setup

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0;

            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            } // for

            context.write(new Text(tag), new LongWritable(sum));
        } // reduce

    } // AdderWithTag

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Filter(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    } // main

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // check the number of arguments, show the usage if it is wrong
        if (args.length != 3) {
            showUsage();
            return -1;
        } // if

        // get the arguments
        String input = args[0];
        String output = args[1];
        String tag = args[2];

        // create and configure a MapReduce job
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        conf.set(Constants.PARAM_TAG, tag);
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "tidoop-mr-lib-count");
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setJarByClass(Count.class);
        job.setMapperClass(UnitEmitter.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Adder.class);
        job.setReducerClass(AdderWithTag.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

        // run the MapReduce job
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    } // main

    private void showUsage() {
        System.out.println("...");
    } // showUsage

} // Count
```

The command executed, and the output logs:

```
$ hadoop jar target/tidoop-mr-lib-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.telefonica.iot.tidoop.mrlib.Count -libjars target/tidoop-mr-lib-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar tidoop/numbers tidoop/numbers_count onetag
15/11/05 17:24:52 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/11/05 17:24:52 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
15/11/05 17:24:53 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
15/11/05 17:24:53 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
15/11/05 17:24:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201507101501_23002
15/11/05 17:24:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/11/05 17:25:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/11/05 17:25:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
15/11/05 17:25:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201507101501_23002
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 25
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=5350
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=1
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=8702
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=6
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=1968928
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=108226
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=598001
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=6
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=2920
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=355663872
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=124
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=328683520
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1466642432
15/11/05 17:25:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=0
```

The content of the output file:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /user/frb/tidoop/numbers_count/part-r-00000
[frb@cosmosmaster-gi tidoop-mr-lib]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/frb/tidoop/numbers_count/
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 frb frb          0 2015-11-05 17:25 /user/frb/tidoop/numbers_count/_SUCCESS
drwxr-----   - frb frb          0 2015-11-05 17:24 /user/frb/tidoop/numbers_count/_logs
-rw-r--r--   3 frb frb          0 2015-11-05 17:25 /user/frb/tidoop/numbers_count/part-r-00000
```

Any hints about what is happening?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?... From the code it is like your mapper has to emit only one value..And you are adding the input path but not using any data from it right?

Comment: from the logs your map output record is zero

Comment: The code is about counting the number of lines of the files within the input folder. Yes, I already noticed the mapper is not outputting anything.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. I'd try using Mapper (identity mapper) with your job.

If the Mapper does not output anything there must be something weird with your hadoop installation, or job configuration.

Comment: The weird thing is other different MapReduce jobs work properly. Thus, it is something with this particular code... and I cannot figure out which is the issue :S

Comment: What are you trying to do with mapper code?. You are emiting same key irrespective of input value always and you replaced LongWritable with Object for offset calculation.